# Configure Android Studio to apply one format to code on file open and a different format on file save

Tags: android, android-studio, code-formatting

I find plenty of info on getting Studio to reformat code before saving, but that's only half the battle.

The whole reason we need to reformat on save is that different devs prefer editing in different formats.

I've found nothing on how to automatically open files in your preferred code formatting style but automatically save them in the team's default code formatting style.

Is it simply not possible?

Comment: Not possible.
If you want to commit your code in a different format than you work on, there is git and android studio setting

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible: Open with code formatting style A but save with code formatting style B.

If you work in a Team, You should change your code formatting style to the team code formatting style.